# i am using a function handle dates but somhow the dates are ending in wrong day

Tags: javascript, date

I am using this code to parse my date in the dash format and then use a new date feature

```
function parseDate(dateString) {
  var parts = dateString.split("/").reverse().join('-');
  return new Date(parts);
}

function getDayOfWeekUTC(dateString,type,show,dFormat) {
  let daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  if(dFormat == 'dd/MM/yyyy') {
  console.log(dateString);
    var date = parseDate(dateString);
    console.log(date);
  }else{
    var date = new Date(dateString);
  }
  let dayIndex = date.getDay();
  let dayOfWeek = daysOfWeek[dayIndex];
  return dayOfWeek;
}
```

right now f i choose from calendar as i am in Atlantic timezone

i see the dateString as:

`Thu Jan 11 2024 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Atlantic Standard Time)`

but it is ending up on wednesday as dayofweek instead of thursday, how can i fix it, because even gulf countries use dd/mm/yyyy formaat, i tested with `UK`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean--you say you see it as `Thu Jan 11 etc` then say it's Wednesday. It's not clear what input you're providing or how it's wrong. I'd suggest making an executable snippet with data so we can see the exact issue without guessing.

Comment: The date is being parsed in UTC, but displayed in Atlantic time. That's 4 hours earlier, so it's the day before.

Comment: Midnight Thursday UTC is 8pm Wednesday Atlantic.

Comment: so how should i fix, even my functon name is UTC, but i am no using a UTC day, its getDay()